# Executing member function on each comma-separated object

Tags: c++, cimg

Here is the relevant code from the [full listing](http://sorj.de/?p=168):

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
  CImg<unsigned char> src("Tulips.jpg");
  int width = src.width();
  int height = src.height();
  int depth = src.depth();

  //New grayscale images.
  CImg<unsigned char> gray1(width,height,depth,1);
  CImg<unsigned char> gray2(width,height,depth,1);

  // ... 

  (src,gray1,gray2).display("RGB to Grayscale");
}
```

How does the line `(src,gray1,gray2).display("RGB to Grayscale");` work? How is the `display` member function applied to each of the objects in the comma-separated list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CImg`](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html) overloads `operator,` which returns a [`CImgList`](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImgList.html) object which is a list containing the two `CImg` objects given as operands. That object also overloads `operator,` to allow `CImg` objects to be added to the list.

The expression `(src,gray1,gray2)` is equivalent to `((src,gray1),gray2)`. The inner set of parentheses, `(src,gray1)`, create the `CImgList`, and then `(...,gray2)` appends `gray2` to that list, returning a reference to the same list. `CImgList` has the member function `display`.

Comment: Good explanation for what seems a very ugly design. Overloading `operator,` like this seems like pure obfuscation evil to me.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that overloading operator,() necessarily implies a ugly design is stupid.
There are lot of useful and clever ways to overload this operator, and CImg does it perfectly well. Do you imagine that the C++ standard would allow it if it was always 'stupid' as you say ?
In this example, the C++ code reads very well, it is definitely more simple (but equivalent) than writing
    CImgList(src,gray1,gray2).display();

As CImg is a library to speed up the writing of image processing algorithms (used mainly for prototyping), this kind of construction is definitely useful.